# Limit for custom parameters of custom Firebase Analytics events?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I didn't find this in the documentation - is there some limit on the number of custom parameter a custom event might have?

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/properties) does mention a limit of 25 user custom parameters, but what about event custom parameters - is there a similar limit?

Comment: It's worth noting that for reporting (at least in free plan) you can only specify up to 10 text parameters and 40 numeric parameters per app (at the same time). https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both event and user parameters are limited to 25.

LogEvent method docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#public-method-summary

Answer (score 37):

I collect the information based on all the official documentation, hope you helps

## Custom Events and Parameters Limitations

- **23** Automatic Registered *Events* - [Source](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485)
- **500** Custom *Events* - [Source](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/firebase/android/events) and [Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event.html)
- Up to **25** custom `parameters` per *event* - [Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param)
- Up to **50** custom *event* `parameters` per ***project*** - [Source](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304)
- From the **50** custom `parameters` only **40** must be numeric `(Long, Double)` and **10** textual `(String)` values - [Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#parameters_1)
- `Parameter` names can be up to **40** characters long alfanumeric with underscores - [Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param)
- `Parameter` textual values can be up to **100** characters long - [Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#parameters_1)
- Up to **30** events per project as conversions - [Source](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317522)

Comment: Note: If you add the same custom parameter in 3 different events, it will be counted as 3 out of your 50 quota.

Comment: Martin Daniel - for predefined parameter value character count is 100 or 10

Comment: @VenkaTeshuser5397700 the limit is 50 custom events which only could be 40 numeric values (Long, Double) and 10 alphanumeric (Strings with 100 characters long)

Comment: Thanks martin Daniel. i have faced some issue in fire base analytics predefined value can you please help me details in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57660104/android-firebase-analytics-predefined-and-custom-parameters-not-working

Comment: I just answer your question @VenkaTeshuser5397700

Comment: @PrasadPawar as of 2021,  from the [documantation:: Deprecation of custom parameter reporting](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/10075209?hl=en&visit_id=637582506532733686-2178476032&rd=1) I think the count will still  be 1 out of 50... quoting, "With event-scoped custom dimensions and metrics, parameters are identified for property-wide dimensions and metrics, allowing you to create a single dimension or metric based on a parameter and report on it for as many events as you wish."

Answer (score 4):

**Custom-parameter reporting limits (2020)**

You can identify up to 100 custom event parameters per project (50 numeric and 50 text) to include in reporting by registering those parameters with their corresponding events.

The ability to create up to 100 parameters is available with App + Web properties. If you're using Google Analytics for Firebase, you need to [upgrade to an App + Web property](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9379599).

If you are not using an App + Web property, then you can identify up to 50 parameters per project (40 numeric and 10 text).

More details :
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304

Answer (score 1):

### Custom-parameter reporting limits (2019)

> Firebase lets you specify up to **25 custom parameters per event** (Android or iOS).
>
> You can also identify up to **50 custom event parameters per project (40 numeric and 10 textual)** to include in reporting by registering those parameters with their corresponding events. Once you register your custom parameters, Firebase displays a corresponding data card in each related event-detail report.
>
> Each parameter that you specify counts toward the project limit of 50. For example, if you specify the same parameter for 3 different events, then that counts as 3 of your 50.

Source: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304

Comment: Don't miss the last point of the answer. As mentioned, even if you specify the same parameter for multiple events, all those same-named parameters would be considered different and each of those would count against your limit of 50.

Comment: from the [documantation:: Deprecation of custom parameter reporting](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/10075209?hl=en&visit_id=637582506532733686-2178476032&rd=1) I think the count will still  be 1 out of 50... quoting, "With event-scoped custom dimensions and metrics, parameters are identified for property-wide dimensions and metrics, allowing you to create a single dimension or metric based on a parameter and report on it for as many events as you wish."