# How to group events parameters by event on firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

I'm working in a react native application that uses analytics using react-native-firebase, I had something like this:

```
Analytics.logEvent('event_click', { target: 'accept', screen:'MainScreen' });
```

What I want on firebase, is to group the 'target' by 'screen' param for example or simply to see the params grouped and not separately.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are automatic registered events on Firebase that track the screen views, look at this [source](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485).

I recommend to organize your events according to this picture to get better insights about the information you need and also check the limitations about custom event limits and parameters [Custom Events and Parameters Limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57117064/3976000)

Hope it helps

[image]

Comment: Thank you Martín, but my question goes more for distinguish my parameter in different screen, for example, accept Button click in the mainScreen from accept Button click in the notificationsScreen.

And what I want in analytics is to know is how many clics the user gave to "accept" button in different screens. There are many "accept", "continue" buttons in my app and I'm using the name of the button as a target data.

Comment: You can create a custom event that register the number of times that the button accept was clicked for every screen.
`Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("button_accept_clicked", acceptTimes);
bundle.putString("button_cancel_clicked", cancelTimes);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("custom_event_screen_a", bundle);`

Comment: ohh! the problem is that I understood everything wrong, I think that will solve my problem :D. Thank you Martin!

Comment: @OscarAlarcon I'm also integrating GA for Firebase with my RN project, have you managed to log a custom event like how you wanted it?