# Firebase custom events count are more than the firebase limited event count

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase Event logging to make custom events on my game. The documentation says that only 500 unique distinct events can be logged. but my console events count is now 542. Also how many inbuild custom events are triggered, i found an answer here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38115542/limit-for-custom-parameters-of-custom-firebase-analytics-events), says 23. If thats the case it should give me only 523 right? Am I looking the data in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between event types and log entries.

> *From [Firebase Analytics - Log Events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=android):*
>
> If your app needs to collect additional data, you can log up to 500 different Analytics Event types in your app. There is no limit on the total volume of events your app logs.

To word this another way - you can set up 500 different events named things such as "opened-app", "purchased-item", "shared-high-score", "sent-game-item" and "defeated-boss" - each containing different data to be logged.

These events can be logged an unlimited number of times which is why you have accumulated more than 500 events in your event log - the list of events might contain 200 "opened-app" events, 60 "purchased-item" events, and so on totalling 542 different entries.